# Use same .binding file in another WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I use WebSphere MQ 7.0, followed necessary steps and configured it. Can I use same .binding file in another WebSphere MQ ?

WebSphere MQ\java\bin\JMSAdmin.config entries as below

```
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
PROVIDER_URL=file:/C:/JNDI-Directory
```

Comment: Do you mean another installation of WebSphere MQ or another queue manager?

Answer (score 1):

The .bindings file is the backing store for the FileSystem JNDI provider. You would typically conenct the JMS based applications to this to load the Connection Factories and Destinations.

A single JNDI store can hold multiple objects and they don't all have to represent connections to a single Queuemanager.

So if you're asking do I need another JNDI store for another queuemanager, no not necessarily.

Comment: Does the binding file have to be updated each time a new queue or other object is created?

Comment: When you use a file system context as the provider for JNDI - the .bindings file will be udpated whenever you add a new object, or update an existing one. 

If you add a new queue or topic or queuemanager to your MQ network AND you use JNDI to provide JMS applications with their resources an update will be needed. 

Never edit the bindings file direct, always use JMSAdmin or MQ Explorer or another JNDI editor. That file, though human readable, is not meant for editing directly.